# Webscraping and performing multiple post actions without Selenium?

Tags: python, post, server, python-requests

I recently started with python and built some local webscrapers, now I am building one for a client on his webhosting which should receive data and then send it to PHP. The problem is that I need to do multiple actions when trying to scrape the page. Added some images to make my problem more clear.

Is it possible to make posts with something like BeautifulSoup? Or is there some sort of alternative for selenium on hosting / server based? Thanks in advance!

```
def getRequest():
    url = 'https://www.wozwaardeloket.nl/'
    myobj = {'accept': 'true','akkoord': 'Verder'}
    z = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
    return(z.text)
```

[1 First page accept some sort of cooke](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IXX3.png)
[2 enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGCJO.png)

Comment: Someone that can help me out giving me some more information? Would be apreciated a lot!